# How do you go from watts to lumens?

Tags: optics, energy, visible-light, dimensional-analysis, si-units

let's say you have a light source and using a solar panel or photoelectric diode you can absorb all the emitted light, which would produce some amount of power outputted by the solar panel. How would you then calculate the lumens? and I'm not talking about some rule-of-thumb calculation like every 10 watts is 80 lumens.

Comment: Lumens is a unit that quantifies the amount of visible light a source emits. Watts is a unit of power. You cannot directly convert between them without more information. Do you want an explaination of the process if you have that extra info? Or were you hoping it was a simple relationship?

Comment: Additionally, solar cell efficiency is strongly wavelength dependent. If all you know is measured power, you cant do what you desire.

Comment: right so I would also need to figure out the wavelength it seems, I'm trying to measure the luminosity of any light source, in this case, let's say an LED for example. I'm trying to find a way to relate the energy absorbed to the luminosity, I understand the energy absorbed is not equal to the energy emitted to account for that I was going to either use the spec sheet efficient of the solar panel or calculate it in a simple setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a two part process:

- The solar panel produces a certain wattage output
- The electical energy is converted to light energy

Simplisticly **solar panels** are rated in efficiency at specific temperature and light path conditions. This is provided by all reputable manufacturers and measured in Watts output per 1000 Watts insolation under specified conditions.  If desired you can go into much more detail regarding response across the spectrum, efficiencies at various temperature and more, BUT in most cases a simple Watts per kW of insolation under specified conditions is adequate.
Typical figues are in the 17%-22% range for conversion of solar to electrical energy.

- Wikipedia [AM1.5 air mass specification](https://wiki2.org/en/Air_mass_(solar_energy))
- NREL [Even more detail on conditions](https://www.nrel.gov/grid/solar-resource/spectra-am1.5.html)
- Buy your own miniatute test sun [here](https://g2voptics.com/products/pico-solar-simulator?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=GAds+SS+SolarSimulator+Standards-Search&utm_term=am1.5&utm_content=ad_540949867197_matchtype=p-network=g-device=c-adgroupid=126684192696&gclid=CjwKCAiAheacBhB8EiwAItVO2-szAY0QPggFNgHmZKLLWkri07R-yZHC30DuHUJ_RKzmD1e5nb72UhoCtFAQAvD_BwE)
- Much more - image search [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=solar+panels+am1.5&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALiCzsaL2VvJaFcXOHMEJGfPVJUVpspIPA:1671073596982&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwin2ZCh0vr7AhUlumMGHcG1ClcQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1920&bih=1009&dpr=2)

**Light output in lumen** from a given radiator (typically an LED) is also specified by manufacturers - usually in lumen per electrical watt input. This too is under specified conditions. Typically either at 20 degrees C - which is almost always lower than actual die temperature due to electrical heating or, for more modern lighting orientated devices, at say 90C or 105C - which corresponds more closefly to actual die temperatures during operation in higher power LEDs. Output is also at specified voltage and cuttent input - and this is often at values lower or substantially lower than maximum ratings.

Typical modern "white" LEDS have outputs in the 120 - 200 lumen per Watt range. Some more recent devices have outputs of 220 lumen/watt and a very few are higher.

Lumen ratings are dependent on wavelength as they are relatd to eye response. A deep-blue near UV source will have extremely low lumen/watt ratings and output at such short wavelengths is often specified in mW of light energy.
Maximum lumen per mW are achieved at the peak spectral response wavelength of the human eye - nominally 550nm wavelength. This is a "sort of yellowy green colour" - and the reason why some fire-engines are coloued "sort of yellowy green" rather than red.

- Lumen per Watt - image search. Each image is a related webpage [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=lumen+per+watt&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALiCzsZnQQNUOmW9wSpJmaNIvbChtESmvw:1671073693765&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO9KPP0vr7AhXNxjgGHVjvBKkQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=1009&dpr=2)

---

The relative sensitivity of the (standardised) human eye at various wavelengths of light is shown in the image below.
This image is from this page [Sensitivity of the human eye](https://www.giangrandi.org/optics/eye/eye.shtml)

To avoid confusion, I recommend starting with considering light bright enough to see colours.
The photopic curve relates to light above about 5 mW per square metre - where the "cones" in the centre of the eye give colour vision. This is about the level of light in a dimly lit corner of a room with a single central light bulb.
The scotopic curve relates to very low level light where the rods in the periphery of the eye give mainly monochrome vision.

Peak bright light response is defined as being 683 lumen for a source of 1 Watt of 550 nanometre light on one square metre. At very low light levels the eye operates in a monochrome viewing mode and somewhat different resuslts are obtained.

[image]

Lumen / Lux / Candella comparison [here](https://www.imbema.com/en/transport-and-logistics/what-is-the-difference-between-lux-lumen-and-candela/)

Useful [What is lumens? How to Choose the Right Lighting Lumens?](https://www.upshine.com/blog/what-is-lumens-how-to-choose-the-right-lighting-lumens.html)

And [Response of the eye to light](https://www.sunledind.com/news-hidden2/eye-response-to-led)

Comment: that chart is handy thank you, I see what you are saying, so if you wanted to go about measuring the 'brightness' of something or how many lumens it's outputting how you would go about doing this? as you said it dependant on the wavelength having a peak at 550nm, so is there an equation that relates the wavelength, and the incident energy to lumens?

Comment: @sourenpash See added material. It is easy to get confused with too much detail to start. IF you are interested in practical application and white light I recommend that you look at LED bu;bs with a given lumen and lumen per watt rating and observe how bright they are in typical applications. You will probably easily get confused if you start with photoic and scotopic responses, eye sensitivity curves, relative lumens at different wavelenghts at the same power etc. That comes later.

Comment: I understand, so start small and build up, I was planning on doing a little research project to see how the apparent brightness drops throughout the day, something like a lumen vs time graph. so should I take a more experimental approach then? for example check how much energy is absorbed when a led with a known lumen output is used as the source and compare that to the ambient lighting. then repeat this with different wavelength light(colors) and superimpose them?

Comment: Also, I just read the sensitivity of the human eye article you attached and I see they have a table could that table be used for example if I know 50 watts of energy are being used to illuminate at 507nm would it be simply 1700*50+307*50?

Comment: @sourenpash  Good question. Note that that is for illumination of 1 square metre AND that the chart is for 1 Watt of radiant light - NOT the radiators wattage rating. || The 307lm is scotopic response - from rods at under about 3 lux. The 1700 is for photopic response at higher levels. While both rods and cones no doubt combine I expect that the monochome scotopic response would not be relevant. (I may be wrong). Regardless, this is for a "standard eye" and (I imagine that) response of any given eye is likely to vary +/- 300 lm around the 1700 nominal.  | 1700 x 50 is probably "close enough".

Comment: If you are dealing with white LED lighting the radiator is usually rated in lumens per watt electrical input. So eg a 150 l/w white 50 W LED will produce 150 x 50 = 750 lumen net, summed across the lamps output wavelength distribution.

Comment: If you can give an example of what you are actually trying to understand or measure in more detail it will mak it easier to provide a good answer. Adding a specific example to the question would help.

Comment: Yeah, sorry been super busy trying to measure how luminosity drops relative to our perception throughout the day, so basically, the rate of change of the luminosity drop from sunrise to sunset. I ended up finding a sensor that gives me a LUX reading across the full spectrum IR-Visible. So I'm no longer using the solar panels, the sensor is called grove digital light sensor. I may still use the soar panels to compare data and see how I could get the solar panel to the same reading as the sensor. but still I would love to hear your suggestions.